# How to convert List<Stream<MyUser>> to Stream<List<MyUser>> on flutter 3

Tags: flutter

Here is my get method from firestore:

```
static Stream<List<MyUser>> getUsersByList(List<String> userIds) {
     final List<Stream<MyUser>> streams = [];
     for (String id in userIds) {
       streams.add(firebaseFirestore
           .collection('user_profile')
           .doc(id)
           .snapshots()
           .map((DocumentSnapshot snap) =>
               MyUser.fromMap(snap.data as Map<String, dynamic>)));
     }
 
     return 'here is a return data'
 
     // return StreamZip<MyUser>(streams).asBroadcastStream();   }
```

Then i need get result to this method:

> StreamProvider<List>.value(
> value: UserProvider.getUsersByList(userIds),
> initialData: [],
> child: HomePage());

But StreamProvider requires Stream<List>, then i have to convert List<Stream>. In flutter older version it use StreamZip, how to convert it in flutter 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's proper solution. But, it works for me.

```
 List<MyUser> users = [];
        StreamController<List<MyUser>> controller =
            StreamController<List<MyUser>>();
        for (String id in userIds) {
          Stream<MyUser> user = firebaseFirestore
              .collection('users')
              .doc(id)
              .snapshots()
              .map((DocumentSnapshot snap) =>
                  MyUser.fromMap(snap.data as Map<String, dynamic>));
    
          user.listen((event) {
            users.add(event);
          });
        }
    
        controller.add(users);
    
        return controller.stream;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).